# How to upgrade Hyperledger Fabric binary images

Tags: docker, upgrade, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, binaries

I would like to know how to upgrade Hyperledger Fabric binary images. For example, I already configured blockchain business network on Hyperledger Fabric v1.0.3, and want to upgrade to v1.1.0-preview level images while maintaining the existing ledgers and blocks. 
Could anyone help me, how to upgrade Hyperledger Fabric platform-specific binaries without any negative impacts on existing business network ?